# How to share function or variable address between c and assembly filese in same project using GCC compiler on ARM Cortex M4

Tags: c, arm, gcc, cortex-m4

I am using a micro-controller with ARM Cortex M4 processor and GCC - GNU ARM compiler.

Some functions are written in c in .c file and in assembly in .asm file.

My questions are as follows :

1. How can I share the addresses of the functions/variables between c and assembly files?
2. How can I call c function from assembly and vice-verse?
3. How can I pass function arguments in above cases?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Stack Overflow? It is purely a software question not electronics.

Comment: The linker (`ld`) should do that - use the same name in C and assembly, and `ld` should resolve them to the same address. Check its output. And you can use `objdump` to inspect the resulting object file.

Comment: @Andrew Yeh.. u r right. I will over it to sack overflow.

Comment: Can anyone provide a example for this?